# Springs 3.0 loading external properties file

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to Load the external properties file from filesystem in springs 3.0 however I am getting filenotfound exception while the file clearly exist in that location.

I am trying this on a windows machine, Websphere liberty and Java8.

I have following code in commonbeans.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file:/C:/AllBackup/DB.properties"/>
```

I Need to load external properties file in springs 3.0 from commonbeans.xml, however not sure why its breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to remove "classpath:"? When your location starts with the "classpath:" prefix, spring will try to load classpath resource.
It looks like that you need to use file resource, by specifying only "file:" prefix.
Also I would propose to remove the leading slash. After "file:" prefix, you need to specify path as you would do it for java.io.File.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:C:/AllBackup/DB.properties"/>
```

See table 4.1
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-introduction